# Using move commands in heroku and package.json file

Tags: node.js, linux, heroku

I am using `mv` command in my build script in my package.json file to move a directory to another one like this:

```
mv node_modules tools
```

But it not working. I don't get any error for this but the next errors show that the directory didn't move. If I use `cp -r` it will copy the directory without a problem but moving it's my problem right now. Any help?

Edited: This is a part of my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "build": "cp -r node_modules tools ; cd tools ; gulp --dark-mode --prod"
},
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? It looks like the "solution" to an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: In any case, please [edit] your question and show us the build script (and your `package.json` in case your build script is in another file).

Comment: @Chris I need to move my `node_modules` to `tools` and then run `gulp` command in tools directory to create my assets.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `node_modules/` is a pretty standard directory in the JavaScript world. What makes you think you need to rename it? And won't that prevent your dependencies from being found at runtime? This is _definitely_ an XY problem. If we can fix the core issue—whatever has made you think this is necessary—the question about renaming that directory goes away.

Comment: Please now share your `gulpfile.js`.

Comment: @Chris I am using PHP to run my web application and I just use yarn and gulp to handle my dependencies. So I need to first install dependencies using `yarn` command and I will get `node_modules` directory. Then I need to move this directory to `tools` directory and cd to this directory to perform `gulp` command. I just need `node_modules` to create my assets and even I can delete it after build. Then, NO, I don't need it.

Comment: Why does it matter whether the directory is called `node_modules/` or `tools/`? I _strongly_ suggest leaving `node_modules/` alone, even if you are not using it at runtime today. At a glance, anybody seeing that folder knows what it is.

Comment: @Chris I am not trying to rename it. I am trying to move it to the tools folder.

Comment: Moving and renaming are the same thing, hence they use the same command (`mv`). But the arguments are important, as are existing files and directories. If a `tools` directory does not exist, `mv node_modules tools` _renames the directory in-place_. Are you saying you want to end up with `tools/node_modules/`?

Comment: @Chris Exactly! `tools` directory already exits with bunch of files.

Comment: Are you _entirely sure_ that the `tools/` directory exists? Where does it come from? If it _exists_, your command should work. If it does not, your command would do something different.

Comment: @Chris I have my gulp files in `tools` and I want to run it there. That is exactly why I don't know what's the problem here. Maybe it will run `gulp` command before moving is completed?

Comment: Using `;` to separate your commands should wait for each one to finish, but it doesn't check for success before moving on. `&&` would be better. I still don't understand why you are trying to move `node_modules/`. Why don't you just `cd tools && gulp`?